# angularjs ng-class evaluates only once

Tags: angularjs

I have the following twitter bootstrap navbar html:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li ng-repeat="module in modules" ng-class="{active: ('{{ '/' + view.name }}' == '{{ module.url }}')}">
        <a ng-href="#{{ module.url }}">{{ module.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As Chrome inspection shows at runtime it becomes:

[image]

AngularJS version is 1.0.6.

As you see, the first `<li>` tag's class is "active" when the page first time loaded. After that ng-class is not re-evaluated, even if url has changed (see highlighted line). Why is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ng-repeat compiles the template, it will replace all the `{{ }}` with the result of the expression, and from that point on you'll have what Chrome Inspector shows you.

Get rid of all the `{{ }}`:

```
ng-class="{ active: ('/' + view.name == module.url) }"
```